# What is the mathematical term describing a pipe or a tube?

Tags: terminology, math-history

I am interested in this unanswered question [Pipe-fitting conditions in 3D](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1278739/pipe-fitting-conditions-in-3d) and so I was trying to find information about it.

If the 3D curve $f(x(t), y(t), z(t)) = 0$ is a line I think that the *pipe of diameter $D$ around it* can be called *the surface of a cylinder*, but what is a proper mathematical term for describing that surface when $f$ is not a line? Tube? Pipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe in this case, the proper mathematical term for the region would be tube (or tube domain, depending on your focus), so the corresponding surface would be *the surface of the tube*.  While pipe is not (to my knowledge) a formal mathematics term, it is used as a physical example in enough problems (both real and created) that the meaning would be just as clear.

Consider: [Mathworld definition of 'tube'](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tube.html)

Comment: +1 it was so simple... I looked at the "SEE ALSO:" section at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedCylinder.html and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cylinder.html and I did not find *tube*...

Answer (score 0):

> With reference to a curve $C$ with  continuously turning tangent in a
>   metrical space of any number of dimensions, we define a 
>   *tube* as the locus of points at a fixed distance $\theta$, called the *radius*, from $C$, the distance being measured in each case along a geodesic perpendicular to $C$.

HOTELLING, Harold. Tubes and spheres in n-spaces, and a class of statistical problems. *American Journal of Mathematics*, 1939, 61.2: 440-460.